# How to route to an interface (not VIA an interface)

Tags: linux, routing, ip

I have defined a `dummy0` interface:

```
sudo ip link add dummy0 type dummy
sudo ip addr add 200.200.200.0/24 dev dummy0
```

The interface is there alright:

```
$ ip addr show dummy0
50: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:f7:18:50:6f:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 200.200.200.0/24 scope global dummy0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But I can not reach it:

```
$ ping 200.200.200.1 -c 1 -W 1
PING 200.200.200.1 (200.200.200.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 200.200.200.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Routing seems to be wrong:

```
$ ip route
default via 172.16.8.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000
172.16.8.0/23 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.9.220 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev br-fcb6a17207d6 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5009391df1c5 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-def793c8b10c proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-79ca860054eb proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown
172.20.16.0/24 via 172.16.8.1 dev eno1
172.20.96.0/24 via 172.16.8.1 dev eno1
172.20.192.0/24 via 172.16.8.1 dev eno1
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-13a8dc17b2c2 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 linkdown
192.168.42.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.5 linkdown
```

How do I route traffic to the `200.200.200.0/24` to this interface?

The obvious candidates do not work:

```
$ sudo ip route add 200.200.200.0/24 via 200.200.200.1 dev dummy0
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.

$ sudo ip route add 200.200.200.0/24 dev dummy0
Error: Device for nexthop is not up.
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to instantiate dummy inteface to just add another local address. You can add arbitrary address to any interface, for instance loopback: `ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev lo`.

Answer (score 1):

you configured `200.200.200.0` as ip addr on dummy0

you try to ping `200.200.200.1`

Comment: It's a /24 network

Comment: You're not adding all 256 IPs of the /24 network though. The /24 is the subnet mask. You're command is "add 200.200.200.0 which is part of a /24 network, as an IP to the interface dummy0", not "add this whole range of 200.200.200.0/24 to dummy0".

Answer (score 1):

you can not reach `dummy0` because the interface is down, as you can see on you command

`ip addr show dummy0` --> `state DOWN`

the interface is down because its a dummy so there is no real way to know its state because it is not really connected to any network.

you can force the interface to up with `sudo ip link set dummy0 up`

then you can ping you own irregular address

```
ping 200.200.200.0 
PING 200.200.200.0 (200.200.200.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 octets de 200.200.200.0 : icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 temps=0.063 ms
64 octets de 200.200.200.0 : icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 temps=0.048 ms
64 octets de 200.200.200.0 : icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 temps=0.058 ms
```

when the interface is up there is no need to add route, it will just show up.

```
ip route
default via ...
200.200.200.0/24 dev dummy0 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.200.0
```